# Symfony. при попытке отправить email он не отправляется, а сохраняется в таблице messenger

Tags: email, symfony, messenger

- создаю новый проект Symfony
- подготавливаю пользователей к установке регистрации *symfony console
  make:user*
- создаю регистрационную форму *symfony console make:registration-form*
- подключаю *symfony composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle*
  для отправки писем при регистрации
- в *.env* прописываю *MAILER_DSN=...*
- провожу миграции, и всё такое.
- захожу на сгенерёный роут */register*
- заполняю форму, отправляю.

отправка писем идёт через

```
$this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
            (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from(new Address('***@***.com', 'My_Sender'))
                ->to($user->getEmail())
                ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
        );
```

всё стандартно. код полностью сгенерённый, и я его ещё не правил.

**всё ок**. никаких ошибок

## писем нет.

но зато в таблице messenger_messages *(эта таблица создаётся сама при выполнении миграций. я её создаваться не просил. очевидно, что из-за компонента messenger, который входит в стандартную поставку "нового проекта" symfony)* появляется новое сообщение.

symfony я только изучаю, и мне вообще непонятно как заставить письмо отправляться, вместо (ну или хотя бы после) сохранения его в таблице messenger_messages.

в обучалке, по подсказке которой я это всё делаю, вместо сохранения в таблице — всё отлично отправилось :(

#### таки как мне отправить письмо? :(

если просто подскажете, как выключить messenger, чтобы письма отправлялись без его помощи — тоже пойдёт :)

Comment: настройки messenger покажите, скорей всего в нем стоит роут для мейлера https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#sending-messages-async

Comment: ну или отправляйте очередь запуском `php bin/console messenger:consume async`

Comment: ну да. в настройках мессенджера стоит, что майл отправляется асинхронно.

        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async

Comment: но вот как очередь-то запустить? вариант с консолью представляется мне оооооочень странным. не буду же я всю оставшуюся жизнь каждые пару минут запускать очередь на случай, что кто-то зарегается, и ждёт письма для подтверждения :)))

Comment: и в доках messenger я не нашёл команды для пуска очереди. возможно, потому что с английским дружу не сильно :)

Comment: _не буду же я всю оставшуюся жизнь каждые пару минут_ ... настройка супервизора, чтобы постоянно консьюмер ждал отправки https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#supervisor-configuration

Comment: прелесть messenger в том, что вы можете из командной строки просмотреть статусы очередей, переотправить ошибочные, возможность автоматического повтора через промежуток времени (если почтовик лежал), возможность запуска нескольких консьюмеров для отправки большого кол-ва писем, распределение ролей отправки на другие сервера

Comment: ага. только для настройки супервизора нужен системный доступ к юниксу, а на виртуальных хостингах никто доступ к ядру вам не даст :)

Comment: можете повесить на крон команду отслеживания очереди, например на запуск каждый час, в команду добавьте ключ `--time-limit=3600`. Тогда воркер остановится через час, а крон его снова поднимет

Comment: то есть пользователь зарегистрировался, а письмо с подтверждением придёт через час? кхм. я, понятное дело, не спец. но что-то мне подсказывает, что ооооочень маловероятно, чтобы создатели symfony решили выстрелить себе в ногу, вводя дефолтную асинхронную отправку почты с помощью  messages, подразумевая, что нужно будет патчить ядро, чтобы таки отправлять почту, либо занимаясь постоянным гашением и рестартом демона.

Comment: нет. при запуске воркер запускается и продолжает работать "ловя" на лету письма и отправляя их. выше я предложил ограничить его работу часом, после чего ПЕРЕзапустить. При запущенном воркере отправка писем осуществляется практически мгновенно. Но если у вас не планируется большой нагрузки, то, конечно, можете и отключить мессенжер

Comment: кхм. это вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отключение messenger для отправки писем оказалось весьма простым.

надо просто добавить message_bus в

**config/packages/mailer.yaml**

```
framework:
  mailer:
    dsn:'%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
    message_bus: false
```

и теперь всё отлично отправляется, а не складируется в очереди.